# RouteCollection first rout wirking fine but second will thrown 404 error

Tags: asp.net

I am using below code for page routing. First is working fine but second route doesn't working. Always thrown 404 error.

```
 void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routeCollection)
    {
        routeCollection.MapPageRoute("RibbetPay", "Offer/{PaymentID}/{UserName}/{PaymentTitle}", "~/Offer/UserCreateOffer.aspx");
        //routeCollection.MapPageRoute("Profile", "Offer/{UserName}", "~/Offer/UserPublicProfile.aspx");
        routeCollection.MapPageRoute("Route2", "Offer/{UserName}", "~/Offer/UserPublicProfile.aspx", false, null, null, new RouteValueDictionary { { "isProfile", "yes" } });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routeCollection)
{
    routeCollection.MapPageRoute("RibbetPay", "Offer/{PaymentID}/{UserName}/{PaymentTitle}", "~/Offer/UserCreateOffer.aspx");
    //routeCollection.MapPageRoute("Profile", "Offer/{UserName}", "~/Offer/UserPublicProfile.aspx");
    routeCollection.MapPageRoute("Route2", "Offer/{UserName}/{random1}/{random2}", "~/Offer/UserPublicProfile.aspx", false);
}
```